# how to disable vertical scrolling while user scrolls horizontally ?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIScrollView` in a `UIView`. I'm using my `UIScrollView` in pagingEnabled mode. I don't want to allow users scroll bidirectionnally at the same time.What i mean is,if user starts to scroll horizontally, i want to disable vertical scrolling and vice-versa. How can i accomplish that  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use property directionalLockEnabled of UIScrollView

```
 directionalLockEnabled A Boolean value that determines whether
 scrolling is disabled in a particular direction

 @property(nonatomic, getter=isDirectionalLockEnabled) BOOL
 directionalLockEnabled Discussion If this property is NO, scrolling is
 permitted in both horizontal and vertical directions. If this property
 is YES and the user begins dragging in one general direction
 (horizontally or vertically), the scroll view disables scrolling in
 the other direction. If the drag direction is diagonal, then scrolling
 will not be locked and the user can drag in any direction until the
 drag completes. The default value is NO

 Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In
 UIScrollView.h
```